# Apache LimitRequestBody - no effect on SSL/binary data

Tags: apache, http, https

I have a service that accepts attachments as multipart form-data in POST requests. I want to limit the size of attachments the server accepts to prevent abuse.

But I can't get Apache LimitRequestBody configuration parameter to work. The server allways accepts my requests - no matter what I configure. I'm expecting HTTP 413 to be thrown when exceeding the request size.

My setup: Load Balancer -> Apache (v2.2.12) -> Jetty

Here is my apache configuration:

```
Listen 11443

<VirtualHost _default_:11443>
    LimitRequestBody 102400
    LimitXMLRequestBody 102400

    <Location /one/myapp>
        LimitXMLRequestBody 102400
        LimitRequestBody 102400
        SetEnv proxy-sendcl 1
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/myapp
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/myapp
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /one http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse /one http://localhost:8080

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      ...host.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   ...host.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile ...host.crt
    SSLProxyEngine on

</VirtualHost>
```

Installed are (among others) mod-ssl and mod-qos.

My request looks like this:

```
POST https://myhost.com/one/myapp/myressource HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: ...
Accept-Language: en_US
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="----=_Part_16_248..."
MIME-Version: 1.0
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: myhost.com
Content-Length: 5760260


------=_Part_16_248...
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=data.raw
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="data.raw"

... (binary data) ...
```

Why does LimitRequestBody not work in my case?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that directive LimitRequestBody does not apply on proxied requests. At least not in version 2.2 which is in use in my case. See: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44758

The problem seems to be fixed in more recent version though. See: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1066444

As a workaround I check the Content-Length header for the size and reject chunked requests.